# Starting emacs in daemon mode freezes, emacsclient is not able find a socket

Tags: daemon, crash, emacs-daemon

I cannot launch the emacs daemon anymore. I do not know what triggered this.
When entering

```
emacs -Q --daemon -v
```

I get only the following and nothing happen.

```
Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost.
Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem.
Starting Emacs daemon.
```

Starting `emacsclient -c` returns:

```
 $ emacsclient -c
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

    --socket-name
    --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
    --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
```

I tried to update emacs without success. Do you know what is going on? How can I solve this?

Comment: You should add some information about what really happens and why you think the daemon doesn't launch anymore.  The above warning can IMHO be safely ignored. For me the daemon refuses to start, when my session contains files that need interaction (like a passphrase for a gpg encrypted file).

Comment: @UweKoloska : I say the daemon freezes because emacs does not run.

Comment: What does it mean: _emacs does not run_?  For me it was twofold: 1. _emacs_ produces a crash 2. running _emacs --daemon_ does not got to background, but responds to _emacsclicent_.  After long searching, I recreated all installed packages (I used cask and pallet) and the error was gone.

Comment: There's a pending edit to this question which looks kind of strange: are you and the editor the same person? @Flow if you and OP are different people, I suggest posting your edit as a comment / perhaps as part of an answer (as steps to figure out what the problem is).